# How to handle out of memory gracefully in shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell, out-of-memory

Is there a way to gracefully handle out-of-memory conditions in a shell script?

```sh
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/sh
i=asdf
while true; do
  i="$i $i"
done
$ bash test.sh
test.sh: xrealloc: cannot allocate 18446744072098939008 bytes
```

Many programming languages allow handling out-of-memory exceptions using simple try-catch constructs. Is it possible to gracefully handle out-of-memory conditions in shell scripts / Bash as well? How?

Would it be possible to either free temporary buffers and attempt to continue execution, or do some custom error handling (save state) and exit with error?

Comment: Well, you cannot use `trap` on this one.

Comment: My only idea is to do the potentially memory using operations in a subshell. then the parent can inspect return codes or error messages. In general though out of memory is very hard to deal with, beware the oom-killer.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of.  Instead, when you hit a problem like this, the normal approach is to raise the limits via `ulimit`.

```
ulimit -m N # for the heap
ulimit -s N # for the stack
```

However, to programmatically detect it, you'd have to do functionality similar to what `strace` does and watch for `ENOMEM`.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing as elegant as a try/catch on *out of memory* exception for Bash.

But you do have options for monitoring your memory consumption yourself.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html

The simplest thing is to monitor the Kernel's OOM (out of memory) score for your process like this:

```
cat /proc/$$/oom_score
```

See more on the origin of the OOM score here:
https://serverfault.com/a/571326/177301

The OOM score is a roughly *percent-times-ten number*.

Using your example, that would work like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

i=asdf
while true; do
  i="$i $i"

  if [ $(cat /proc/$$/oom_score) -gt 200 ]
  then
    echo "Abort: OOM score over 200" 1>&2
    exit 1
  fi

done
```

I experimented with this a little. On my Ubuntu VM the kernel would kill the script right after the OOM score hit 241. Your mileage may vary.